# get the specific title attribute of wordpress image

Tags: php, wordpress, image, media

I would like to ask how to get the specific title attribute of wordpress image from wordpress media?

Those information that are being inputted upon uploading the images life, title, alt captions, description.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find specific attribute of wordpress image attachment.

```
   <?php 
    $attachment_id = 8; // attachment ID

    $image_attributes = wp_get_attachment_image_src( $attachment_id ); // returns an array
    if( $image_attributes ) {
    ?> 
    <img src="<?php echo $image_attributes[0]; ?>" width="<?php echo $image_attributes[1]; ?>" height="<?php echo $image_attributes[2]; ?>">
    <?php } ?>

    An array containing: 

    [0] => url
    [1] => width
    [2] => height
    [3] => boolean: true if $url is a resized image, false if it is the original or if no image is available.
```

Answer (score 1):

This should help you.

```
$title = get_post(get_post_thumbnail_id())->post_title; // Title
$caption = get_post(get_post_thumbnail_id())->post_excerpt; // Caption
$description = get_post(get_post_thumbnail_id())->post_content; // Description
```

Comment: Hai Ferrrmolina I tried using the $title but the title of the post appears and not the title of the specific image from the media library.

Comment: i saw a code from http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/185396/getting-the-image-title-alt-attribute-from-the-gallery-shortcode

but it outputs blank.

Comment: Look that: http://www.bobz.co/how-to-get-attachment-image-caption-alt-or-description/

Comment: I cant see the title of the image on that site only caption and description where post excerpt and post content are used,not the title image from the library.